# how to use ng-checked inside a uib-tabset

Tags: angularjs

With the example of ng-checked as documented at:-

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

If you place the first checkbox of 'check me to check both', the checkbox is not checked if it is placed inside a uib-tabset-heading after you have selected it.

Can anyone explain why this is the case and what you can do to persist the checked state.

Comment: This sounds like a scope problem, try having your ngChecked property inside an object rather than at the root of the scope, something like `$scope.myobj.checkedProperty`. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is a scoping issue. The `uib-tabset` directive creates a child scope for the tabs. For prototypical inheritance to work properly the `ng-model` directive needs to specify a property of an object.

```
  <input ng-init='obj={}' id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="obj.master">
  <br>        
  <uib-tabset active="active">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">
          <label>Check me to check both: 
                               <!-- Always include a dot in ng-model-->
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.master"></label><br/>

    </uib-tab>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/q3YayKFFcjM8kNeG42Wj?p=preview)

For more information, see [The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)